# Excluir palavras de um arquivo

Tags: csv, awk, sed, texto

Eu tenho um arquivo `CSV` e tenho essa lista de palavras aqui: https://gist.github.com/alopes/5358189

O arquivo `CSV` possui 3 colunas, Texto, user.name e Classe e possui cerca de 100K de linhas. Preciso excluir da primeira coluna do `CSV` todas as palavras que aparecem na lista.

Podem me ajudar?

Comment: Você quer excluir só a palavra ou tirar a linha toda?

Comment: Só a palavra mesmo.

Comment: Temo como colocar alguns registros do seu CSV pra ver como tá o padrão?

Comment: cara, desculpa a demora pra responder, estou extremamente ocupado esses dias, vou ver se posto ainda hoje um trecho do arquivo.
Valeu!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando Perl (desculpa...) mas fácil de traduzir para awk

```
$ cat stoplist.txt 
de
a
o ....

$ cat ex.cvs 
meu caro amigo;jjoao;classe a
eu ando a aprender weka;Thyago;classe b
mas a sua sintaxe dá-me algumas dores de cabeça;Thyago;classe a
```

Seja rmstopwords o seguinte ficheiro Perl:

```
BEGIN{  $patt="que";      ## contruir uma regexp reg com as palavras
  open(G,"stoplist.txt");
  while(<G>){chomp; 
    $patt.="|$_" if $_    ## patt="que|de|a|o|..."
  }
}

$F[0] =~ s/\b($patt)\b//g;  ## no primeiro campo, subst(patt por "") 
print join(";",@F)
```

Aplicado ao nosso ficheiro `ex.csv` dá:

```
$ perl -naC -F';' rmovestopwords t.cvs 
 caro amigo;jjoao;classe a
 ando  aprender weka;Thyago;classe b
    sintaxe dá- algumas dores  cabeça;Thyago;classe a
```

Comment: Opa!
Muito obrigado, vou tentar e aviso aqui se funcionou.
Valeu!